# Spring Boot Microservice depends on another Microservice in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, spring-kafka

I have developed two Springboot michroservices ex- service1 and service2. service2 microservice having dependency of service1.

I've added dependency of service1 in service2 pom file and working expected in eclipse while running service2. but when I deployed in Jenkins and I've created project(Jenkins Job)  for service1 and ran with maven goal 'clean install', project builds successfully.

When I created project(Jenkins Job) for service2 and running the Jenkins Job, build is failing because service2 is not able to find the dependency of service1.

Comment: Where do you publish service1? Is the artifact server where service 1 is published in the repository list of service2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue Resolved!!! whenever we are using spring dependency in depedent project we don't need to add maven/spring compiler plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Your jenkins should be configured with an artifact repository like Nexus, if this is the case make sure the maven config of your project is set to publish the artifact to the repository.

On the other hand, it's not a good practice to make dependencies between microservices. Instead communications could be done via other protocols REST/HTTP,...

Comment: I configured Jfrog artifact repository and successfully able to find the artifact in Jfrog. but while adding the dependency in another project I am facing the same compile time issue like NoClassDefFoundException. for dependent project I've created maven project in Jenkins and provided the repository artifact configuration than also I am facing compile time issue. Any Idea ?

Comment: You have to configure maven to look for dependencies on your Jfrog repo, you can do that on the settings.xml file on your maven installation folder.

Comment: While I am running the Jenkins Job, I checked dependency is downloading but not getting any Idea why I am facing compile time error. I've added below repository configuration in pom.xml of dependent project. <repositories>
  <repository>
   <snapshots />
   <id>repository-id</id>
   <name>repository-name</name>
   <url>repository-url</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>