# Jankins artifact configuration for dependent Job

Tags: jenkins

I've created two Jobs in Jenkins, JobB is dependent on JobA.
While configuring JobA, I am doing post build action to deploy artifact in Jfrog and it is successfully deployed.
But while configuring JobB, I am configuring prebuild setup with to find artifacts and providing the detail, when I am running Job I've checked that JobA jar is downloading but then also I am facing compile time issue, I've written repository tag in dependent pom.xml.
But then also I am facing compile time issue.

Comment: Provide the console log of your jobs. It is difficult to understand what is happening without seeing the actual errors.

Comment: [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /app/jenkins_slave/workspace/NetworkAssurance/Network Ticketing/acut-kafka-ticket-reader-maven/src/main/java/com/bell/sa/kafka/messagereader/listener/MessageReader.java:[9,40] package com.bell.sa.kafka.bean.processor does not exist

Comment: Issue Resolved!!! Please check below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768517/spring-boot-microservice-depends-on-another-microservice-in-jenkins